# Does sweating have any correlation with how effective my workout is?

Tags: weightlifting, sweat

I start my workout with a 5 minute very fast run to warm up. Then I start sweating.

Then I move to weights which causes me to sweat more in the first 20 minutes, after that my sweat usually goes away and I finish the rest of the workout without sweating or only minor sweating.

Does sweating have any correlation with how effective my workout is?

In the early parts of my workout I am sweating more, I probably have a higher body temperature, is the weight lifting I am doing at that time more effective than the lifting I am doing at the end of the exercise when I am not sweating?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, it doesn't have a direct relationship with the efficiency of your workout.
If you're sweating, that could be caused by a multitude of things (clothes your wearing, temperature of gym, speed of workouts, etc.)
Usually sweating while working out is a good indicator that you're get a nice workout in, but that doesn't mean sweat=good workout/no sweat=bad workout.

Some people sweat a lot during workouts, some don't sweat much at all.  In short, it's very hard to find a solid correlation between sweat and an "effective" workout.

If you want to sweat more while at the gym, try to keep your heartrate up while you train.  This can be done by taking shorter rests between sets, and working with fewer reps and higher weights.

Answer (score 2):

In short, No.  Sweating is a physiological reaction to heat.  It’s a mechanism for your body to control heat.  It’s a means of [thermoregulation](http://www.healthline.com/health/thermoregulation#Overview1).   In a nutshell, when your muscles “heat” up (from exercise), your body works to cool you down.  And, contrary to some opinions, sweating also does not correlate to fat loss even though you may see a slight decrease in weight due to water (sweat) loss.